# GwtQuery DND - How to stop event propagation and prevent default

Tags: gwt, gwtquery

I have two drop panels one over the other and need the ability to grab the gwt `NativeEvent` from a GwtQuery DND `DropEvent` so that I can call stopPropagation and preventDefault. Unfortunately this appears to not be available in the GwtQuery DND DropEvent class. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The DropEvent is the gwtquery.plugins.droppable.client.events.DropEvent which is a GwtEvent and not any kind of DomEvent.

Answer (score 1):

OK, typical I find the answer a couple of minutes after posting the question. The solutions is in your DraggableWidget to getOption().setGreedy(true). This enables stopPropagation and preventDefault.